# How to parse specific substrings from a string or json(string)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have one string which is response from api call:

```
x='{"show permission allowed to 16": "show permission to 16\\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tAllow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 18:library to group 16(Temp):teacher:\\n\\tNo Allow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 20:Gym to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tCheck ALL-00\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\n\\n#"}'
```

and this is the json format of `x`

```
json={'show permission allowed to 16': 'show permission to 16\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\n\tAllow ALL-00\nSchool permissions from group 18:library to group 16(Temp):teacher:\n\tNo Allow ALL-09\nSchool permissions from group 20:Gym to group 16:teacher:\n\tCheck ALL-05\nRTYAHY: FALSE\nRTYAHY: FALSE\n\nSwitch#'}
```

I have to extract the the numbers after the substring `from group` (in the example above the numbers to be extracted are `17` and `20`) and the permissions `Allow ALL` and `Check ALL`. PermissionS are in the format `Allow ALL-dd` where `dd` can be from `00` to `FF` and I should also extract the permissions in the format `Allow ALL-00` and `Check ALL-05`

Since a second permission `No Allow ALL-09` has `Temp`, this substring must be skipped and the permission shouldn't be stored.

Required output:

```
Fromlist=['17','20']

Permission=['Allow ALL','Check ALL']

Permission_Num=['Allow All-00','Check ALL-05']
```

Since this is the response of api call, number of permissions keeps changing. 
Say for example: Permission `Check ALL` might not appear in response if it is not configured at that point of time or a new permission like `Change ALL` might be added. So the code should be such that it should check for all possible permissions of format `perm ALL-dd`.

I have tried this code:

```
l=x.find("permissions from group ")+len("permissions from group ")
print(l)
y=x[l:l+2] #this is to extract 17
from.append(y)
if((x.find("permissions from group ")) and (x.find('\\t'))):
    l=x.find('\\t')+len('\\t')
    e=x.find('-00') #Here I want to have -dd where dd can be 00 to ff
    s=x[l:e]
    perm.append(s)
```

Comment: Can you put exactly the string of the exptected output?

Comment: try using regex

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I have

Comment: @Braca Im new to python I don't know how to use regex

Comment: I don't think this is your original problem, but where you are stuck at. The data seems super messy, and since you're a beginner, I think the original problem is probably simpler. Are you not getting this from a configuration file you need to parse ?

Comment: @IMCoins this is the response im getting from api call

Comment: I think you should rephrase your problem then. You are trying to parse a string that looks like to be a json structure. Since I imagine you process the request using `requests` with the response method `.text`, I encourage you to use `.json()` instead If I am right.

Comment: @IMCoins if x was json object instead of string would it be easier?

Comment: If the object looks like a json structure in the 'raw answer', then it was meant to be processed as a json structure. I believe it will be way easier. Try solving your problem again dealing with the json structure (which *basically* consists of dictionnaries and lists). Even if you are a beginner, I think you can manage this on your own. But feel free to come back here to ask for more help.

Comment: @IMCoins I didn't understand how to search for particular substrings for e.g.: Allow ALL in lists

Comment: Why `from group 18` is not considered?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi because in "School permissions from group 18:library to group 16(Temp):" there is (Temp) which means temporary and it should be skipped

Comment: See edit2 in my answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Im not a developer. Im still a student. I'll definitely try to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to extract. Anyway you must use regular expressions. In python the library is `re`.

So for example if you want to extract the all substring from `from group 17` to `Allow ALL-00` or `Allow ALL-dd`:

```
import re
str1 = '{"show permission allowed to 16": "show permission to 16\\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tAllow ALL-00\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\n\\n#"}'
res = re.sub(r'.*(from group 17.*Allow ALL-..).*', r'\1', str1)
```

If instead you need just the 2 characters after `Allow ALL-`:

```
t = re.sub(r'.*from group 17.*Allow ALL-(..).*', r'\1', str1)
```

**EDIT 2 (according to the last edit in your question)**

You can do the following ([the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398956/1714692) helped me with the result):

```
#creates a list of tuples. Each tuple has as first element
#the number found after 'from group ' (reppresented by the 2 
#dots in the regular expression and the second element is a string
# containing all the characters after `\t` until 2 characters after the
# string  'ALL-'
res = re.findall(r'from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*?[^(Temp)]?(?:(?!Temp).)*?\\t(.*? ALL-..)',str1)
#[('17', 'Allow ALL-00'), ('20', 'Check ALL-00')]
#build the lists you want as output
#we build the lists you want as output
Fromlist= list()#['17','20']
Permission=list()#['Allow ALL','Check ALL']
Permission_Num=list()#['Allow All-00','Check ALL-05']
for el in res:
    Fromlist.append(el[0])
    Permission.append(el[1].split('-')[0])
    Permission_Num.append(el[1])
```

Comment: I want to extract "Allow ALL-dd" and "Allow ALL" But the permission could change Sometimes it says "No Allow ALL-dd"

Comment: I have added all details in my question

Comment: This is almost correct but we remove the element if "temp" is found irrespective of what the permission is

Comment: Your question was and still is very ambiguous and honestly I am getting lost at patching the answer for your changes in the question and comments. Should the string be ignored because it has `No allow` or because it has `Temp`? It is becoming like a guess game and that's no good.

Comment: You can also try to continue yourself: I think the difficult part was extracting the substrings. That is done already.

Comment: I have made it pretty clear that the string should be ignored if there is "Temp" and No allow is just a permission. It doesn't literally mean you don't allow. Thanks for the guidance. I'll try to continue

Comment: I did but since I have reputation less than 15 my upvote doesn't reflect immediately

Comment: I have updated the question for new response. I cant figure out how to do because response is too complicated. Please help

Comment: If you want anything different you should not modify your question but ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **very** unclear. I think you should clarify your need with the person that asked you to do this.

If I listen to you, and want to process the json you mentionned...

```
d = {'show permission allowed to 16': 'show permission to 16\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\n\tAllow ALL-00\nRTYAHY: FALSE\nRTYAHY: FALSE\n\nSwitch#'}

data = d['show permission allowed to 16']
data = data.split('\n')
data = [item.strip() for item in data]
print(data)
#['show permission to 16', 'School permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:', 'Allow ALL-00', 'RTYAHY: FALSE', 'RTYAHY: FALSE', '', 'Switch#']
```

As you can see, doing this, your data is processed into a simple list. If you make a clearer question, I might explain the code.

Comment: I have added much details to my question