# How to use '?' to extract optional substring between two matching pattern in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, substring

I was [answering this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54363394/1714692)n. Consider this string

```
str1 = '{"show permission allowed to 16": "show permission to 16\\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tAllow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 18:library to group 16(Temp):teacher:\\n\\tNo Allow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 20:Gym to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tCheck ALL-00\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\n\\n#"}'
```

and suppose I want to extract the number after each substring `from group` and the substring after `\\t` having the smallest matching string.

I did this with the following regular expression

```
import re
res = re.findall(r'from group (\d+).*?\\t(.*? ALL-..)', str1)
```

output is:

```
[('17', 'Allow ALL-00'), ('18', 'No Allow ALL-00'), ('20', 'Check ALL-00')]
```

Now between each substring I am extracting (the number and  the substring after `\t`) there might be an optional substring, whose value is `Temp` I want to extract (if present). For example between `18` and `No Allow ALL-00` there is the substring `Temp` I would like to extract.

I tried using `?` as follows:

```
res = re.findall(r'from group (\d+).*?(Temp)?.*?\\t(.*? ALL-..)', str1)
```

but the corresponding second element of the resulting tuples is always empty:

```
[('17', '', 'Allow ALL-00'), ('18', '', 'No Allow ALL-00'), ('20', '', 'Check ALL-00')]
```

while I was expecting something like:

```
[('17', '', 'Allow ALL-00'), ('18', 'Temp', 'No Allow ALL-00'), ('20', '', 'Check ALL-00')]
```

How to extract substrings in this case? What is the mistake I am doing?

One further question: suppose I want my resulting list not having this element (the one containing `Temp`): should I just use `[^]` and then the corresponding matching pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not capturing `Temp` is because you have made it optional due to which `.*?` consumes it, and `Temp` does not get captured in your optional group.

To solve that problem, you can use negative look ahead to reject `Temp` getting captured except any other character using this regex,

```
from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*?(Temp)?(?:(?!Temp).)*?\\t(.*? ALL-..)
                   ^^^^^^^^^ This rejects Temp getting captured except any other character
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `from group` - literal matching of this text
- `(?:(?!Temp).)*?` - `?:` means its a non-capturing group which by default is a capturing group and this means that capturing anything but stop when you see `Temp` string and `*` means capture zero or more characters. So this captures any string which doesn't contain `Temp` and `?` means as less as possible
- `(Temp)?` - Optionally capture `Temp` if present
- `(?:(?!Temp).)*?` - Again capture any character zero or more times except `Temp` just like above
- `\\t` - capture this literally
- `(.*? ALL-..)` - Capturing any character as less as possible followed by a space followed by literal `ALL-` followed by any two characters

Hope this clarifies the regex. Let me know in case you have any further queries.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o6DYOP/1)**

Sample Python Codes,

```
import re

s = '{"show permission allowed to 16": "show permission to 16\\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tAllow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 18:library to group 16(Temp):teacher:\\n\\tNo Allow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 20:Gym to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tCheck ALL-00\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\n\\n#"}'

arr = re.findall(r'from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*?(Temp)?(?:(?!Temp).)*?\\t(.*? ALL-..)',s)
print(arr)
```

Prints,

```
[('17', '', 'Allow ALL-00'), ('18', 'Temp', 'No Allow ALL-00'), ('20', '', 'Check ALL-00')]
```

**Edit: For listing only tuples that does not contain `Temp`**

You will need to use this regex to avoid matching substring that contains `Temp` string within the match,

```
from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*\\t(.*? ALL-..)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o6DYOP/2)**

Sample Python code,

```
import re

str1 = '{"show permission allowed to 16": "show permission to 16\\nSchool permissions from group 17:student to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tAllow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 18:library to group 16(Temp):teacher:\\n\\tNo Allow ALL-00\\nSchool permissions from group 20:Gym to group 16:teacher:\\n\\tCheck ALL-00\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\nRTYAHY: FALSE\\n\\n#"}'

arr = re.findall(r'from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*\\t(.*? ALL-..)',str1)
print(arr)
```

Prints,

```
[('17', 'Allow ALL-00'), ('20', 'Check ALL-00')]
```

Which does not contain the tuple having `Temp`

Comment: You mean reject `Temp` being captured by `.*`? Also can you explain the syntax `?:(?!Temp).`?

Comment: Sure, let me add detailed explanation in my post

Comment: Last question: to extract only the ones withoug `Temp` the expression `re.findall(r'from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*?[^(Temp)?](?:(?!Temp).)*?\\t(.*? ALL-..)',str1)` is working but is it the correct one?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: If you want to extract only the ones that does not have `Temp` within it, you should not use that regex I gave in my answer as that will list all three tuples. Use this regex instead `from group (\d+)(?:(?!Temp).)*\\t(.*? ALL-..)` as this will not list the tuple where `Temp` is found. Let me also update my answer.

Comment: Pleased to help brother :)